# How to produce a log scale FFT with MatLab

Tags: matlab, fft

It's my first time performing an FFT within MatLab by experimenting with some example code from the MathWorks website.  I was wondering if it was possible to take the code I have and transform the `x axis` to a log-scale representation rather than linear.  I understand most of the code, but it is the `x axis` line of code that I'm still not 100% sure exactly what it is doing apart from the `+1` at the end of the line, which is that fact that MatLab's indexing structure doesn't start on `0`.

My code so far is:

```
[y,fs] = wavread('Wav/800Hz_2sec.wav');
NFFT = 4096;
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/length(y);
f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

frequency usually comes out in linear scale from Discrete Fourier Transform. if you want, you can make a new frequency vector in log scale and interpolate the results you already have

```
fnew=fs/2.*logspace(log10(fs/length(y)),0,npts);
Ynew= interp1(f,Y(1:NFFT/2+1),fnew);
```

where `npts` is the length of your new frequency vector. for just plotting

```
loglog(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1));
```

honestly IMO, the interpolation thing doesn't work very well because FFT of real signals produces strong peaks and troughs in spectra, so unless you smooth your spectrum first, the interpolated spectrum won't look as nice

Comment: If you want just the x axis to be logarithmized, use `semilogx` instead of `loglog`.

Comment: Or equivalently do `set(gca,'xscale','log')` after the `plot` line